# How does this property hold? If $r\geq0 $ and $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 , r\lt \epsilon $ then $r=0$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be sequence in $\big<X,d\big> $
>
> Prove that $p_n\rightarrow p$ and $ p_n\rightarrow p'$ $\implies p=p'$

When we proved this in class we made use of a property which is:

If $r\geq0 \qquad$  and $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 , r\lt \epsilon \qquad \qquad$ then $r=0$

I basically didn't understand how this property holds. Intuitively yes it's true but is there a rigid proof to show this?

Comment: Perhaps try proving the contrapositive. That is can you show that if $r > 0$, then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $r \ge \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r \geq 0$ and $\forall \varepsilon > 0, r < \varepsilon$, then suppose by contradiction $r > 0$. Then if you fix $\varepsilon := \frac{r}{2}$ you get a contradiction. Thus $r$ must be $0$.

Suppose $p_n \rightarrow p$ and $p_n \rightarrow p'$. Then fix $\varepsilon > 0$, you can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$d(p_n,p) < \varepsilon \quad \text{ and } \quad d(p_n,p') < \varepsilon \quad \text{ for } n > N.$$
By nonnegativity, triangular inequality and symmetry of $d$:
$$0 \leq d(p,p') \leq d(p,p_n)+d(p_n,p') < 2\varepsilon$$
but $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, so by the reasoning above you get $d(p,p') = 0$, which by non-degeneracy of $d$ means $p = p'$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $r>0$, let $\epsilon = r$, then we have $r<r$ which is a contradiction.